# I want this query optimized using MySql

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization, subquery, full-text-search

I have a huge record in a user table and I want to show this record in a optimize way. I made a query but they take so much execution time (see query) also I already manage indexes in both table but seriously not success (see explain).

I want each user post count that why I made this query like this:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(up.`user_id`) FROM `users_post` up WHERE up.`user_id` = uf.`user_id`
) AS user_count 
FROM `users` uf;
```

> Expain
>   [image]

Comment: For huge database it might worth precalculating the posts count into a separated `users` table column and using it instead of calculating it each time dynamically

Comment: I want each user post count that why i made this query like this... @zerkms

Comment: I understand that, and you need to precalculate that data and store if the database is big and you need to retrieve that often

Comment: why do you think I don't like it? I didn't downvote it (+1 for making you more positive ;-)

Comment: OK no problem but thank for supporting me @zerkms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like all you are doing is selecting a count of posts per user, for all users.  You don't need to wrap your query into a result set to query from, you should just be able to do it via

```
SELECT user_id, count(*) as totalPosts
   from user_posts
   group by user_id
```

Now, if you wanted additional user information to tag along with it, you could then join to the users table, such as:

```
SELECT users.LastName, users.FirstName, etc, user_id, count(*) as totalPosts
   from user_posts
           join users
              on user_posts.user_id = users.user_id
   group by user_id
```

Also, as noted by zerkms, if this is something you want always as some sort of running overall total, I would strongly suggest updating your users table to have a "totalPosts" column as integer.  Then, whenever a new entry is added to the user_posts table, it just has a trigger to...

update users set totalPosts = totalPosts +1 where user_id = the user ID making the post

Then, you don't have to keep requerying the overall totals.  Like some totals here at S/O, a user has other stats of total points, total awrds, etc.  And for tags following, I'm sure they have a count of how many questions per tag too.  Don't over use COUNT()ing on things that will be future performance killers..

Comment: Deleted my answer and +1 to this as more comprehensive

Comment: PS: not sure it is required there, but probably a small note that sometimes the counter doesn't need to be actual in realtime so to refresh them not by performing increments/decrements on each change, but apply changes in a bulk way

Comment: @Zerkms, thanks for the support and upvote.  Sometimes, just giving a query solves a person's solution (and I've done my share too, especially on basic queries). However, helping newbies to querying and better structuring, normalization and when stored aggregates CAN make sense helps them longer-term to better think of their problems...